# How do Linux OS schedule threads when there are multiple sockets

Tags: c, linux, gcc, numa

For example, in a dual socket system with 2 quad core processors, does the thread scheduler tries to keep the threads from the same processes in the same processor? Because interleaving threads of different processes in different processors would slow down performance in the case where threads in a process have a lot of shared memory accesses.

Comment: It could be related to `NUMA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

On current Intel platforms the BIOS default seems to be that memory is interleaved between the sockets in the system, page by page. Allocate 1Mbyte and half will be on one socket, half on the other. That means that wherever your threads are they have equal access to the data.

This makes it very simple for OSes - anywhere will do.

This can work against you. The SMP hardware environment presented to the OS is synthesised by the CPUs cooperating over QPI. If there's a lot of threads all accessing the same data then those links can get real busy. If they're too busy then that limits the performance, and you're I/O bound. That's where I am; Z80 cores with Intel's memory subsystem design would be just as quick as the nahelem cores I've actually got (ok I might be exagerating...).

At the end of the day the real problem is that memory just isn't quick enough. Intel and AMD have both done some impressive things with memory recently, but we're still hampered by its slowness. Ideally memory would be quick enough so that all cores had clock rate access times to it. The Cell processor sort of did this - each SPE has a bit of SRAM instead of a cache, and once you get your head round them you can make them really sing.

===EDIT===

There is more to it. As Basile Starynkevitch hints the alternate approach is to embrace NUMA.

NUMA is what modern CPUs actually embody, the memory access being non-uniform because the memory on the other CPU sockets is not accessible directly by addressing a bus. The CPUs instead make a request for data over the QPI link (or Hypertransport in AMD's case) to ask the other CPU to fetch data out of its memory and send it back. Because the CPU is doing all this for you in hardware it ends up looking like a conventional SMP environment. And QPI / Hypertransport are very fast, so most of the time it's plenty quick enough.

If you write your code so as to mirror the architecture of the hardware you can in theory make improvements. So this might involve (for example) having two copies of your data in the system, one on each socket. There's memory affinity routines in Linux to specifically allocate memory that way instead of interleaved across all sockets. There's also CPU affinity routines that allow you to control which CPU core a thread is running on, the idea being you run it on a core that is close to the data buffer it will be processing.

Ok, so that might mean a lot of investment in the source code to make that work for you (especially if that data duplication doesn't fit well with the program's flow), but if the QPI has become a problematic bottle neck it's the only thing you can do.

I've fiddled with this to some extent. In a way it's a right faff. The whole mindset of Intel and AMD (and thus the OSes and libraries too) is to give you an SMP environment which, most of the time, is pretty good. However they let you play with NUMA by having a load of library functions you have to call to get the deployment of threads and memory that you want.

However for the edge cases where you want that little bit extra speed it'd be easier if the architecture and OS was rigidly NUMA, no SMP at all. Just like the Cell processor in fact. Easier, not because it'd be simple to write (in fact it would be harder), but if you got it running at all you'd then know for sure that it was as quick as the hardware could ever possibly achieve. With the faked SMP that we have right now you experiment with NUMA but you're mostly left wondering if it's as fast as it possibly could be. It's not like the libraries tell you that you're accessing memory that actually resident on another socket, they just let you do it with no hint that there's room for improvement.

Comment: *Ideally memory would be quick enough...*  Barring a revolution in fundamental physics, RAM is never going to get much faster than it is now: the memory bus is within an order of magnitude of being limited by the speed of light.  Seriously.  (Technically the speed of an electromagnetic wave in copper, which is roughly 2/3 *c* = 20cm/ns. When you add up all the wires, the CPU turns out to be about 20cm away from the RAM.)

Comment: @Zack, yes distance is a problem (things like XDR memory in PS3 have more than one bit in flight down the data bus traces on the motherboard...), but the DRAM cells themselves are dog slow. Even DDR3-2133 is only fundamentally clocked at 266MHz, well over ten times slower than the core; good throughput, rubbish latency. HP's memristor is a lot better - apparently that clocks at >1GHz, 4 times quicker than the fastest DRAM. Anyone for non-volatile main memory?

Comment: Well, there's that last order of magnitude... How many cycles to access, do you know?

Comment: @Zack, do you mean to access memristor memory cells? I'm not completely sure, but I think it's just one. Memristor is a very interesting piece of tech, and if HP/Hynix get it right they're going to clean up. Headline features - 1GHz clock (faster than anything else), non-volatile (like flash), random read, random right (like DRAM), no wear problems (unlike flash), and apparently scales to 1 petabit / cm^2 with current manufacturing tech (much denser than anything else by a long way including HDD). If all true then it's a dream storage solution.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more if used as a DRAM replacement then it's likely that they'd employ a DDR style accessing scheme for memristor too. So there'd still be a CAS, etc. But it should boil down to access times being 4x quicker because the basic memory clock is 4x faster. HP and Hynix are being awfully quiet about all this, but the word is that they've got all the basic tech sorted and are now just planning on playing the market for maximum revenue. So don't expect 1pbit just yet, they'll want to sell us much smaller devices first so they can sell us bigger ones later.

Comment: The density would help too. Imagine if they can get a TByte in 1cm^2. That's physically small. Imagine soldering such a device to a motherboard right next to the CPU. You could then have a very dense pin pattern, so it could be really close to the CPU. So that'd save something like 2ns off the access time.